# Указать в коде информацию об авторстве

Tags: python

Как указать в коде Python (не в комментариях) информацию об авторстве, лицензии, версии, контактные данные?

Comment: Если не в комментариях, то через `print` в начале программы.

Comment: Можно, используя `argparse` поставить в вывод по опции `script_name -h`

Comment: Создайте `setup.py` и соберите в нём необходимую информацию ([не обязательно, что `setup.py` является источником для всех мета-данных](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single_source_version/#single-sourcing-the-version), например, хорошо когда версия доступна после импорта соответствующего пакета (`your_package.__version__`) --  может управляться с помощью [`bumpversion`](https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `__author__`, `__email__`. Рекомендую почитать англоязычную тему SO : [What is the common header format of Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/what-is-the-common-header-format-of-python-files)

Answer (score 0):

Можно,используя двойные кавычки.Технически,это не комментарии,а документация.Но каждый использует для своих нужд.Несколько раз видел,как в самом начале перед кодом была информация об авторе,заключенная в двойные кавычки.